# How to get the assignee of a comment in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

There seems to be no mention in the official documentation of a method to get (or set) the assignee of a comment in a google doc.

Is there any known way, including perhaps some clever workaround, to allow getting/inferring the name and/or email of the assignee of a comment in a gdoc?

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer: There is no such feature at the moment

Getting the assignee of a comment is not available at the moment. As far as the current Google Drive API documentation goes, you can only access the comment's author, status, content, ID, etc. There are no fields for getting the comment assignee. You may request a feature request through [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

### Workaround: Use Drive API v2

This workaround lists all of the comments as well as the author and assignee. However, `an assumption that the first "@email" will be the assignee is in place` since there are no specific fields in the Drive API for listing comment assignee as of the moment.

### Script

You may use the script below as a basis for creating yours. Also, please include `Drive API v2` in the services tab.

```
function getAssignee() {
  var fields = Drive.Comments.list("FILE ID",{ fields: "*" }); //Insert file ID here
  var commentsQty = fields.items.length;
  for (let i = 0; i <commentsQty; i++) {
    var commentAuthor = fields.items[i].author.displayName; //gets the comment author
    var contentValue = fields.items[i].content; //gets the comment content
    var commentResolve = fields.items[i].status; //Checks if the comment is resolved
    var assignee = contentValue.match(/@[^\s]+/g); //extract the assignee assuming that the first @emailaddress is the assignee
    console.log("Comment Author: ",commentAuthor,"\nAssignee:",assignee[0],"\nStatus:",commentResolve?"Resolved":"Not Yet Resolved","\nComment: ",contentValue)
  }
}
```

### Output:

[image]

### References:

- [Comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference#Comments)
- [Comments: List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the answer posted above.

Comment: The Drive API only appears for me when trying to add it as a service with v2 available. Where/how do you add the v3?

Comment: I do apologize for the inconvenience. I have modified the script to work with Drive API v2. Kindly check if it now works on your side.

Comment: The script runs but unfortunately the assumption that the first email mention is the assignee is unreasonable and results in far too many errors (e.g. when a comment gets re-assigned)

Comment: Yes, I understand that the assumption is for comments that do not get reassigned to others. However, that is the only possible workaround that I can think of given the absence of a feature that gets the comment assignee. I suggest sending a feature request to Google's  Issue Tracker (issuetracker.google.com).